# Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in Apache Nifi

Tags: mysql, docker, permissions, apache-nifi, singlestore

I am trying to use Apache Nifi for loading tweets and storing them in memsql database. Loading and processing tweets works great, but when I come to steps of inserting to memsql, more precise when flow comes to ConvertJSONToSql processor, it throws error.

[image: CET ERROR]

This is my setup for JDBC Connection Pool:

[image: Connection details]

Memsql is running on Docker, whose cluster I initialized like this:

```
docker run -i --init `
    --name memsql-ciab `
    -e LICENSE_KEY=$env:LICENSE_KEY `
    -p 3308:3306 -p 8090:8080 `
    memsql/cluster-in-a-box
```

Port 3306 and 8080 were already taken. I also made sure that myuser has all permissions, both to host 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1', as shown in grants.
[image: grants]

When I connect with Windows Powershell or on localhost:8090, both logins work for 'myuser' with password 'pass'. Also both logins have permissions for database 'twitterDB'. What I found weird is, in my Docker cluster I have database memsql, which in it has table users, but I can only run:

```
describe memsql.users;
```

Everything else throws error 'ERROR 1706 (HY000): Feature 'table names conflicting with metadata tables of the same name' is not supported by MemSQL.'. Also, in my JDBC Connection pool in Nifi, if I leave user and password empty, ConvertJSONToSql throws different error, which says that ''@'localhost' user doesn't have permissions for database 'twitterDB'.*.

I have been struggling for some time now with this problem, and I don't know what else to try so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Let's separate the concerns of authentication fail and insert fail.  Try changing Apache Nifi to use the user `root` (no password) and see if the inserts succeed.  Also try inserting data using sql commands from MemSQL Studio (`localhost:8090` in your setup) or from powershell.  Try this with each login: `root` (no password) and as `myuser`.  These tests should help us learn more.

You didn't specify the Docker setup, so assuming Docker Desktop or another local Docker, try increasing CPUs to 4 and RAM to 4 or 8 gigs. I find the developer defaults are often smaller than what works well with `cluster-in-a-box`.

Comment: I solved my problem, it was something i should have predicted, but instead spent hours and hours doing what u specified and more. Problem was I already had running MySQL service, which blocked my database. I turned it off, and restarted docker, and it worked. Thank you for reply anyway.

Comment: Glad you got it solved.  I suspect then you were hitting the MySQL service and that was failing to login.  :D  If this happens in the future, you can change the host port (the first number) like this: `docker run -p 3307:3306 -p 8081:8080 ...` and now the two can coexist.  In theory you already did this as you changed it to `3308`, though perhaps Apache Nil wasn't using the custom port?  In any case, glad it's solved.